# Jar file failed to run when exported from MyEclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jmf

I have written a program which I used Java Media Framework (JMF) Library to capture video from camera and display the video, when I run the program in Eclipse it work will, but when I export the program as runnable jar file, then the program cannot detect the device. I have done some experiment which I will share with you below.

I installed JFM in C drive and I add the libraries from C drive to Eclipse (C:\Program Files\JMF2.1.1e\lib) in this case the program run from Eclipse working will, but when I copied the libraries from (C:\Program Files\JMF2.1.1e\lib) to inside the project  in Eclipse, then the same problem happen which cannot detect the device. 
Now I don’t know how to solve this problem, if anyone knows about this can suggest me. 
Thanks in Advance!

I have tried all below three options to export, but the same problem happened:

[image]

But when I select the first option then Eclipse warn as below:
[image]

Comment: **Do not use** the first option.  I don't understand the 2nd.  I would recommend the 3rd.

Comment: How do you run the exported JAR? from a command line, or just doubleclicking it?

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Can you explain why the first option is bad?

Comment: And to the OP, it's hard to tell, but it sounds like it could just be a path issue.

Comment: @DavidK 'stuffing everything in one Jar' has a number of possible problems, including. 1) SPI information might be lost. 2) Duplication of APIs that should otherwise be installed separately. 3) Legal reasons. 4) Loss of (possibly valid) digital signatures 5) Compaction of natives into the Jar, in such a way as cannot be deployed for an applet or JWS app. ..

Comment: I run the Jar via double click, the other jar files which is exported all runnable via double click

Comment: Add @davida. (or whoever) to notify someone of a new comment.

Comment: @BahramdunAdil OK, assuming this is a classpath problem, can you check if your JAR file has META-INF/MANIFEST.MF in it and if that file contains a classpath, and if that is a valid one (the dependecy JARS are placed where the manifest file says)? If you select the 3rd option during JAR export, Eclipse should create the manifest for you. Check that please.